# Solve the system using Gaussian elimination with back-substitution or Gauss-Jordan elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the system:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_1-3x_3&=-2 \\
3x_1+x_2-2x_3&=5 \\
2x_1+2x_2+x_3&=4
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

This is my very first problem actually using a matrix so here is my attempt

First I setup the augmented matrix:

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&0&-3&-2\\
        3&1&-2&5 \\
        2&2&1&4
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

Then I did $(-3)R_1+R_2->R_2$ which produced:

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&0&-3&-2\\
        0&1&7&11 \\
        2&2&1&4
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

And then I did $(-2)R_1+R_3->R_3$:

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&0&-3&-2\\
        0&1&7&11 \\
        0&2&7&8
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

And then $(1/2)R_3->R_3$:

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&0&-3&-2\\
        0&1&7&11 \\
        0&1&\frac{7}{2}&4
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

And then $(-1)R_2+R_3->R_3$

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&0&-3&-2\\
        0&1&7&11 \\
        0&0&\frac{-7}{2}&7
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

And finally $\left(\frac{-1}{7}\right)R_3->R_3$

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&0&-3&-2\\
        0&1&7&11 \\
        0&0&1&-1
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

But this is not correct according to the solution.  Can someone tell me where I went wrong?  Clearly I did something really wrong here.

Comment: Also, in the last step, after you fix the "augmented" column, you want to multiply the third row through by $ \ - \frac{2}{7} \ ... $ (A warning about solution of systems of equations, by matrices or otherwise:  arithmetic must be handled _very_ carefully, because there is not much of anything that will cause your calculations to hang up, so you can get all the way to an "end" and only discover a problem when you check your answers in the original system of equations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your step: And then $(-1)R_2+R_3->R_3$

If you look at where you have $−11+4$.

Comment: A second error is in the last step, but yes, that's the first mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is at row: $(-1)R_2 + R_3 \to R_3$.